# Why local storage is not working even it should not open after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am using this but the cookies message keeps appearing after everypge refresh and tab opening.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    if (!!localStorage.getItem('firstVisitVisp')) {

        localStorage.setItem('firstVisitVisp', 'true');

        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#cookieConsent").fadeIn(200);
        }, 4000);

        $("#closeCookieConsent, .cookieConsentOK").click(function () {
            $("#cookieConsent").fadeOut(200);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Why there double  `!!` this statement `if(!!localStorage.getItem('firstVisitVisp'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there - just remove the `!!` and change it to `!`:

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('firstVisitVisp')) {...}
```